# SafeArrayTypeMismatchException: The specified array is not of the expected type

Tags: c#, .net, opc-da

I'm trying to read data from OPC DA Server. I'm using the method SyncRead
`SyncRead(short Source, int NumItems, ref Array ServerHandles, out Array Values, out Array Errors, out object Qualities, out object TimeStamps);`
The problem is that I don't know exactly the type of the Array of parameter Values.
I'm doing it like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OPCAutomation;
using EasyModbus;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;


Array ServerHandles = new Array[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];
Array Values = new Array[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];
Array Errors = new Array[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];
object Qualities = new object();
object TimeStamps = new object();
Array Values = new Array[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];

ObjOPCGroup.SyncRead(
   (short)OPCDataSource.OPCDevice,
   ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count,
   ref ServerHandles,
   out Values,
   out Errors,
   out Qualities,
   out TimeStamps
   );
```

when I start the application, I get the error:
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException: The specified array is not of the expected type*

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: minor note: you're declaring `Values` twice; is that a typo?

Comment: Should be an int[] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Array[length]` is an array *of arrays*; you probably wanted an array of something more appropriate, for example a `new int[length]` for an array of integers, or `new string[length]` for an array of strings. We don't know what the API is here, so we can't tell you what they should be. But they almost certainly shouldn't be arrays of `Array`.

Additionally: most of these are passed as `out` parameters, so you *probably* don't even need to initialize anything except `ServerHandles`. The rest could presumably all be `null`? or just initialized via `out var` i.e.

```cs
Array serverHandles = new SomeOtherTypeHere[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];

ObjOPCGroup.SyncRead(
   (short)OPCDataSource.OPCDevice,
   ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count,
   ref serverHandles,
   out var values,
   out var errors,
   out var qualities,
   out var timeStamps
   );
```

Comment: I changed it as You wrote and declared  ```Array serverHandles = new long[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count]; ``` because I found this datatype in some documents of OPC DA Automation. The error message still is show. How can I check which variable or parameter is wrong?

Comment: Ok, I changed declaration to int[] ```Array ServerHandles = new int[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];``` and I got the message: *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Comment: After changes I have the message: ```System. ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range```

Comment: Without knowledge of the API in question, this is impossible for me to answer, sorry. Frankly, P/Invoke layers are hard, and usually best wrapped by someone close to the thing being invoked.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for Your help. I found the solution for this last problem. I populated object ```ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("Some.Variable", 1)``` without saving ServerHanle in the array ```Array ServerHandles = new int[ObjOPCGroup.OPCItems.Count];```. When this array is without handles, then this error *System. ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range* is shown. As quite good reference I can attach the link, how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866803/read-synchronously-from-opc-server . Now I can mark the problem as resolved